# EBean: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class models.User is not enhanced?

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a Play 2.4.6 app that was working fine until two days ago. Since yesterday, I got this error:

```
[[37minfo] - application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[[31merror] - com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager - Error in deployment
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class models.User is not enhanced?
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setEntityBeanClass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1405) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-6.8.1.jar:na]
```

I already looked for solutions but I am still getting that error. Even, I tried using plugin 2.0

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "2.0.0")
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance,

**Update:** In the end, I rewrote the code, removed EBean, and began to use Play Framework's database pool and JDBC's `PreparedStatement`. Works fine. I will leave this question here, hoping it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following:

1. Ensure @Entity annotation is specified on the User class.
2. Ensure application.conf has the ebean package configured for your datasource: `ebean.default=["models.*"]`
3. Ensure `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")` is  in your plugin.sbt file.
4. Ensure you have PlayEbean enabled in build.sbt: `lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)`

Comment: I checked all of that. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: What version of Play are you using? Were there any changes to anything else that may coincide?

Comment: Play 2.4.6, Scala 2.11.6, Sbt 0.13.9, PlayEBean 1.0.0. I tested with PlayEBean 2.0.0 too...

Comment: You can check most recent sbt-play-enhancer version 
[from here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-enhancer)

Answer (score 2):

If you `tried all of the given solutions` and `couldn't` solve the problem, check your project's JDK version.

There is some sort of problem with Java11. **Try Java8 or lower version.**

Comment: This was the problem for me. I was trying to get an old project running on a new M1 Mac with Java 15. As noted at https://github.com/playframework/play-enhancer/issues/23 the Play Enhancer doesnt work for JDK 11+. I got it working on an older machine with Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to try it again with ebean this did the trick for me

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4kmglM48Vc

Comment: It solved my problem when I follow this video instructions and used the plugin `Ebean 4x enhancement`, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of playframework you are using, you may need to change

```
ebean.default= ["models.*", "another.models.*"]
```

to

```
ebean.default="models.*, another.models.*"
```

You can find a bit more details here:
https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/issues/18

Besides that, you will need playEbeanModels to be configured for every module where you need eBean enhancers. For example:

```
    lazy val domainModel = (project in file("domain-model")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean).settings(Seq(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.projectlombok" % "lombok" % "1.18.4",
        "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.197",
        guice),
      playEbeanModels in Compile := Seq("com.mycompany.model.*"), // this should match the package name from above ebean.default="com.mycompany.model.*
      playEbeanDebugLevel := 4
)
```

Some explanations may be found here as well:
https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/issues/25

Answer (score 0):

I would be dropping this for others that none of the above worked for.

In my `application.conf` file i have the following

```
ebean.default=["models.*"] 

ebean.secondary=["ExternalModels.*"]
```

and I was getting the famous

> Bean class ExternalModels.User is not enhanced? error

To resolve that all I did was move my ExternalModels package into a new package and named it `ebean.secondary.ExternalModels`

And boom the error was gone!